# Dropdown with react-bootstrap works in build static file but not when served with web server

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-bootstrap

I have a simple page build in react with react-bootstrap and react-mini-router.

I am using the same code in the react-bootstrap example for navigation for dropdown:

```
render: function() {
        var userName = 'Superman';
        return (
            <Navbar brand="React-Bootstrap">
                <Nav>
                    <NavItem eventKey={1} href="/">Home</NavItem>
                    <NavItem eventKey={2} href="/About">About</NavItem>
                    <NavDropdown eventKey={3} title={userName} id="basic-nav-dropdown" onClick={this.userNameClick}>
                        <MenuItem eventKey="1">Action</MenuItem>
                        <MenuItem eventKey="2">Another action</MenuItem>
                        <MenuItem eventKey="3">Something else here</MenuItem>
                        <MenuItem divider />
                        <MenuItem eventKey="4">Separated link</MenuItem>
                    </NavDropdown>
                </Nav>
            </Navbar>
            )
    }

});
```

When I build the page and open the index as you can see [here](https://kkarimi.github.io/react-bootstrap-test), the dropdown in the menu works as expected and just drops the menu without navigating the page, whether you are in 'home' or 'about'.

However when I use gulp-connect or python SimpleHTTPServer to serve the page at localhost, pressing the dropdown always changes/navigates the page to 'home', even though the dropdown is not a link.

How can this happen?

The full code of example can be found [here](https://github.com/kkarimi/react-bootstrap-test) and problem can be replicated by running gulp which will start the web server.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Update: the problem was a conflict between react-bootstrap and react-mini-router, you can see progress/solution at [this](https://github.com/larrymyers/react-mini-router/issues/42) Github issue.

My temporary fix was to capture the event at RouterMixin's handleClick function.

```
handleClick: function(evt) {
    var dropdownevt = (evt.path[0].id === 'acc-dropdown');
        if (url && self.matchRoute(url.pathname) && !dropdownevt) {    ...
```